# .Net 4.5 bug with MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5, asp.net-4.5

I'm struggling with a framework 4.5 problem. Our asp.net mvc4 web app is running well on a 2008R2 server with .net 4.0 installed but when we upgrade the framework to .net 4.5 we seem to hit some kind of nasty bug:

> Could not load type '...' from assembly '...' because the method '...' has no implementation (no RVA)

This unusual exception is thrown by the framework when getting a type using reflection from the asp.net generated .cs code of a .aspx view. We get a YSOD:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>       **Could not load type 'ASP.views_beherenecli_actielijstecli_index_aspx' from assembly 'App_Web_index.aspx.aeda16c.y-wvrppj, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because the method '__RenderContent3' has no implementation (no RVA).**
>       Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'ASP.views_beherenecli_actielijstecli_index_aspx' from assembly 'App_Web_index.aspx.aeda16c.y-wvrppj, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because the method '__RenderContent3' has no implementation (no RVA).
>
> Source Error:
>       An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>       [TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'ASP.views_beherenecli_actielijstecli_index_aspx' from assembly 'App_Web_index.aspx.aeda16c.y-wvrppj, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because the method '_*RenderContent3' has no implementation (no RVA).]
>          System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
>          System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +73
>          System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateBuildProvider.GetGeneratedType(CompilerResults results, Boolean useDelayLoadTypeIfEnabled) +128
>          System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.CreateBuildResult(CompilerResults results) +103
>          System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetBuildResult(CompilerResults results) +23
>          System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath) +599
>          System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +571
>          System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +203
>          System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound) +249
>          System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerWrapper.System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager.FileExists(String virtualPath) +36
>          System.Web.WebPages.DefaultDisplayMode.GetDisplayInfo(HttpContextBase httpContext, String virtualPath, Func`2 virtualPathExists) +55
>          System.Linq.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext() +245
>          System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) +215
>          System.Web.WebPages.DisplayModeProvider.GetDisplayInfoForVirtualPath(String virtualPath, HttpContextBase httpContext, Func`2 virtualPathExists, IDisplayMode currentDisplayMode) +27
>          System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPathFromGeneralName(ControllerContext controllerContext, List`1 locations, String name, String controllerName, String areaName, String cacheKey, String[]& searchedLocations) +402
>          System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPath(ControllerContext controllerContext, String[] locations, String[] areaLocations, String locationsPropertyName, String name, String controllerName, String cacheKeyPrefix, Boolean useCache, String[]& searchedLocations) +942
>          System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String viewName, String masterName, Boolean useCache) +206
>          System.Web.Mvc.<>c*_DisplayClassc.b_*b(IViewEngine e) +47
>          System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find(Func`2 lookup, Boolean trackSearchedPaths) +176
>          System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult.FindView(ControllerContext context) +110
>          System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +147
>          System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17() +33
>          System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +613
>          System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +263
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass25.b_*22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +240
>          System.Web.Mvc.<>c*_DisplayClass1d.b_*18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass4.b_*3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass4.b_*3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
>          System.Web.Mvc.<>c*_DisplayClass8.b_*3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
>          System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
>          System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288

**Question: Am I the only one with this problem? Does anyone know how to work around this or know a fix?**

note: the code is compiled on a buildserver with framework 4.0. The problem seems really related to .Net 4.5 because when we downgrade to 4.0 the problem disappears.

Things we have tried:

- deleting Temporary ASP.NET files folder
- in web.config use the compilation element and targetFramework="4.5" attribute.

Comment: I don't think that your problem is a bug..

Comment: With ILDASM we verified the problematic assembly dll and noticed that the RVA value of method __RenderContent3 has a value of 0x00000000. Meaning that the method has no implementation. If we see the generated .cs this method sure has a lot of code in it... The assemblies that are ok do not have RVA values of 0x00000000 so this has to be some bug that occurs when asp.net compiles views into dll's.

Answer (score 1):

Using the C# "dynamic" keyword in HTML helper methods seems to be the root of the problem. The main render method gets a RVA value of 0 which is causing the "Method has no implementation (No RVA) exception." error when asp.net tries to resolve the type containing the method.

Comment: Hi Boris, Can you please email a small repro for this issue on netfx45compat@microsoft.com ? Thanks! This doesn't look like MVC specific issue. it is more like CLR issue during compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

[Upgrading target framework from 4.0 to 4.5 for ASP.NET MVC applications](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/prashant_upadhyay/archive/2012/10/19/upgrading-target-framework-from-4-0-to-4-5-for-asp-net-mvc-applications.aspx)

Upgrading an ASP.NET MVC 4 application from .NET 4.0 to .NET 4.5 framework is not easy job.

Comment: What the link suggests is to upgrade the codebase to 4.5 however we cannot upgrade our codebase just yet but instead develop in vs2010 and build for fw4.0. I assumed it was possible to run 4.0 assemblies on the 4.5 runtime? (because MS says there are hardly and breaking changes)